# Correct name of an irregular pentagon with four vertices in a square shape and one protruding perpendicular from the mid point of two of the vertices?

Tags: geometry

What is the correct name of an irregular pentagon that has 4 vertices in a square shape and one protruding perpendicular from the mid point of two of the vertices?

As seen in this image:

[image]

Comment: Pedestrian crossing? Or maybe home plate?

Comment: I was thinking house shape, but I doubt that's a technical term :)

Comment: House was my first thought. In any event it's definitely an irregular  pentagon

Comment: arrow, bullet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_graph), pencil - some nice properties if the triangle is the same as half the square

Comment: This is [monohedral tiling, class 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Pentagons_in_tiling) with angle $B = 90º$.

Comment: Maybe an [augmented square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Augmentation.html)? I like the house idea :)

Comment: Unfortunately truncation only makes sense with 3D solids, so we cannot use the term here.

Comment: "Tented" comes to mind, but I don't know if the word "tented" would conjure this shape in people's minds.

Comment: What do you mean by *correct name*? Why must it have a special name? Why can't anyone just call it what they wish? What is the significance of this pentagon?

Comment: tented, envelope (to enclose a square-shaped card), house, monohedral tiling, class 1... (though the latter, from its name, would likely apply only in a tiling situation)

Answer (score 1):

They are sometimes called *prismatic pentagons*, see, e.g., https://www.amazon.ca/Tapco-Intensity-Prismatic-Pentagon-CROSSING/dp/B008J4Z388

Comment: "Prismatic" refers to the reflective coating on the sign linked to, not the shape.